# How can i add a graphical represntation of the data in spline chart form

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-graphql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx9Nh.png)

I want to add this to my Flutter app, how can I achieve this the data model that I am collecting is:

```
amount: 5.123
category: Health
date: 08-Feb-2023 23:45 PM
```

This is the form of data which I am storing in the firebase

Answer (score 0):

you can use syncfusion_flutter_charts package which give different types of charts for example

[image]

you can also use fl_chart package which also gives a variety of charts one of them is

[image]

read more about their implementation on [pub.dev](https://www.pub.dev)